# Colocar site responsivo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Galera boa tarde, seguinte.

É a primeira vez que to fazendo um site, e na minha cabeça eu faria o site desktop primeiro para depois fazer as modificações responsivas (reduzir tamanho das letras, imagens, alterar algumas colunas, etc...) para celular e tablet.

Então, criei o meu site inteiro e todas as páginas para desktop, pra em seguida fazer do tablet, e depois do celular.

Porém, fui assistir uns videos sobre fazer site responsivo, e o cara disse que se usa um termo "**mobile first**", e se começa a criar o site no tamanho do celular e depois ir aumentando.

Isto é obrigatório? Como faço para tornar responsivo se já tenho o site pronto 100% para desktop?

**E mais uma pergunta**: Eu percebi que a responsividade é só no CSS. É possível mudar alguma coisa no HTML pra ser visualizado somente quando estiver  na tela de celular ou tablet?

Comment: Já ouvir falar em Bootstrap?

Comment: sim e nao, mas irei pesquisar sobre, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Primeira pergunta:**

É possível fazer um site das duas maneiras, como você já desenvolveu o site no desktop, poderá manter o conceito de Desktop first e fazer do maior para o menor. 
O que acontece é que de uns anos pra cá notou-se que a maior audiência dos sites web vinha do celular, logo não fazia sentido criar um layout que fosse lindo no desktop, mas apenas se adaptasse ao celular.
Sendo assim, começamos a desenvolver os layout primeiramente para celular.
Quando se trabalha com mobile first basta seguir a lógica do desktop first de forma reversa. É desenvolvido primeiro a versão celular, depois tablet e por último desktop.
Apesar de mobile first ser uma boa prática, não é obrigatório.

**Segunda pergunta:**

Existem hoje muitos frameworks que ajudam no desenvolvimento front-end. Eles se baseiam em um sistema de grid que ajuda e muito a desenvolver sites 100% responsivos. O mais conhecido deles é o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
Acho válido você dar uma olhada na documentação.

Sobre ajustes de fonts e background no responsivo, é necessário criar no css [@media queries](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/) para aplicar os estilos somente para um determinado tamanho de tela